# How to verify JMeter's performance on a distributed performance test?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I'm doing a REST API performance test, where I have to do a lot of requests simultaneously. To do it I'm using 3 JMeter instances (1 master and 2 slaves).

To give you some more contest, I did a JMeter script with 2 thread groups, and on each group I have 150 threads and a constant throughput timer.

Here is the command line I use to launch the test:

```
./jmeter -n -t ./script.jmx -l ./samples.csv -e -o ./dashboard -R 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.96,192.168.1.175 -Gthroughput=900000 -Gduration=10 -Gvmnb=3 -G ./API.properties
```

In this command line, **throughput** is the total throughput that I'm aiming for the 3 servers (it's value is divided by **vmnb**, my 3rd variable, and then each server do this part of the throughput) and **duration** is the duration of the test.

In this case, the constant throughput should be 900K (300K per server) for 10 minutes. The ramp-up period is 5 minutes (**duration**/2)

Now my question:

If I understood correctly, at the end I should have 900K * 10 minutes = 9000K samples in my result file (per API).

On my JMeter's dashboard, I have only 200K and 160K samples for each url. even if it only manages to see the Master server (I think), I'm far away from the expected results, no?

[dashboard image (I can't upload an image yet...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDBdo.jpg)

Am I missing something or I'm having some performance issues with my VMs, and they aren't able to deliver the high throughput?

I would like to thank you all in advance for your help,

Best regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JMeter master doesn't generate any load, it only loads the test plan and sends it to the slave instances so in your setup you have **2 load generators**
2. Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the threads to **limit** JMeter's throughput to the given value so you need to ensure that you have **enough threads** to produce the desired throughput. If your target is 9M samples in 10 minutes it means 900k samples per minute or 450k samples per minute per slave which gives 7500 requests per second. In order to have 7500 requests per second with 150 threads you need to have 0.02 seconds response time while your average response time is around 1 second.

   Assuming the above I would recommend switching to [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination. They can be connected via [Scheduled Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads to reach and maintain the defined throughput.
3. Also make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as 7500 RPS is quite a high load and you need the confidence that JMeter is capable of sending requests fast enough

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply, I'll try to absorb all of this and see the modifications that you suggest (I'm new to JMeter).

One last question : when you say that I'm only using my 2 slaves as load generators. I have the felling that the 3 work, because I'm launching the jmeter-servers on my 3 machines (the local host IP is passed on my command line), and it seems to run when I launch the test (I have a message "server started") on my console...

Is it possible that this is a false message? (I'm using 2 putty windows to access the master vm)

Comment: If you run both JMeter Master and JMeter slave on the same machine - everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see the links you send me :)

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
I'm sorry to still bother you, but I have one last question for you: my JMeter project has a lot of thread groups (19), do you know if I can put the Throughput Shaping Timer on the root of my project? This way each Concurrency Thread Group will point to just one Shaping Timer? For information, I need to run my groups both simultaneously and in sequence...

Comment: Sure you can, Throughput Shaping Timer obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you put it on the top of the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) (at the same level as Thread Groups) - it will affect all the Samplers in all Thread Groups. If you put it under a Thread Group - it will affect all the Samplers in the given Thread Group. If you put it as a child of a specific sampler - only that sampler will be impacted.

Comment: And even if I run the groups in parallel mode (at the same time), each one will continue it's work without interfering with the others?

Comment: JMeter Thread Groups are independent and know nothing about each other

Comment: Perfect, and really thank you. I'm doing all the changes now
:)